# Laravel session flush with shell.

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Is there a way to flush session in Laravel 5.5 from shell?

Can I use `php artisan tinker` or maybe there is a more easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is used to getting start Session using Tinker, simply issue the tinker Artisan command in the root application directory.Laravel provides a tinker command out of the box. The tinker command uses the `PsySH` library to setup a **`REPL`**

You can use:

Removing An Item From The Session

**Session::forget('key');**

Removing All Items From The Session

**Session::flush();**

Or complete session clear per `userid`:

```
Auth::logout();
Session::flush();
```

[tinker-command](https://stillat.com/blog/2016/12/07/laravel-artisan-the-tinker-command)

Comment: Thanks, but I still have my session... i used `>>> Session::flush();
=> null`

Comment: and it has the same result... Maybe it is because i use a file to store the session?

Comment: I saw some threads here,  where ppl had problems flushing they sessions